# Is StackOverflowError at a collection's toString() method a bug?

Tags: java, collections, stack-overflow

I have written this piece of code to demonstrate:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(list1);
list1.add(list2);
list1.toString();
```

This code will cause the `StackOverflowError`.

However I am aware there is some effort in java's collections to prevent this, for example this code will work fine:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(list1);
list1.toString();
```

Some other languages seem to handle it as well (both cases). Is there a reason the first example is not "sanitized" and the second one is? Is it a bug?

Comment: Detecting cycles in all possible data structure is probably NP-Complete, same as the halting problem.  Java may handle the simple self-inclusion case but probably doesn't bother beyond that.

Comment: It's hard for Java to detect anything beyond self-inclusion because it invokes `toString()` on each of the elements, and there is no way for a "parent" call to `toString()` to indicate to "child" calls to `toString()` which objects have been seen before.

Comment: Detecting cycles in arbitrary data structures would involve adding a `visited` flag to every element node and then clearing all the flags before starting a deep reference. That would involve defining a 'we already cleared this one` flag to prevent infinite cycles during the clearing process...  sorry, but it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: Makes sence, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner it doesn’t require parent-child communication, as every list implementation would only need to know whether it is itself within its own `toString` execution, which could be done with a private thread local within the class itself. However, most people prefer a fast toString() operation…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly a bug - it's more an unfortunate pragmatism. toString should try its hardest not to throw anything (it's a debugging tool, and that'd be quite annoying - there is no real need to report on extraneous circumstances during a toString calculation) - but there are limits to how hard it should try, because toString should also be performant, and easy to write.

The problem is, java is an OO language, and things are encapsulated. There is no way to know that invoking a `toString` on a 'component' object is going to end up calling toString back on yourself again just by looking at what the component is. It's just an object after all (lists can hold anything - including other lists, sets, maps, etcetera). Java, unlike some other languages, also has fully extensible core datatypes: You can write your own implementation of list, and many do. (`java.util.concurrent` has a bunch of very useful implementations of the core collection APIs, for example). Thus, trying to cater to this situation with some sort of internal communication system between collections would put the onus of managing all that on those extending, as well, which is not the pragmatic choice.

There are some very tricky ways, such as trying to catch StackOverflow, or setting a flag in a ThreadLocal and returning an alternate value if this flag is true (because that implies calling the toString on some component object eventually ended up calling toString on you again), but now you have to spec that toString calculations cannot farm out the work to other threads. It's highly unlikely any would, but adding a whole bunch of bizarre caveats to the toString implementation, or making it into a little framework to communicate the concept of recursive componenting, is all doing exactly what is totally inappropriate for a debugging tool: Make it tightly bound, and complicated.

Comment: I think, a `toString()` method using a thread local would solve this issue smoothly, except for one important detail: `hashCode` and `equals` still would be broken, without a contract conforming solution at all. So it’s easier for developers to remember that none of the value-type kind of operations inherited from `Object` would work for a list containing itself (or even simpler to remember: *don’t do it*)…

Comment: @Holger perhaps the overarcing rule is that toString lacks clear purpose (in the name of keeping it simple, perhaps that's not so bad). Had it been specced to be a debugging tool that never throws and always performs, then a list should for example only list its size and the top 100 entries. Heck, even "foo".toString() should not just 'return this', it should return a cutoff string if it is long. In practice, debugging tools tend to do this job of catching exceptions and adding cutoffs.